# Executing a block of code at a certain time with a help of using setInterval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to execute a block of code in a certain time. in order to do that I write a function called `get_current` which get the current time and by using `setInterval` and check the time in short interval, compare it to my desired time. If that condition is satisfied I execute a `console.log()`.

I have tested the code below and got sure that the `checkStart()` is executed in the inteval which is defined in the code but unfortunately that *if condition* is never satisfied. Does anybody have any idea why?

```
var dateString;


function get_current(){

var mydate = new Date();
var mili_real = mydate.getMilliseconds();
var hour_real=mydate.getHours();
var minute_real=mydate.getMinutes();
var second_real=mydate.getSeconds();
     if(minute_real<10)minute_real="0"+minute_real;

     if(hour_real==0)hour_real="12";

     if(second_real<10) second_real="0"+second_real;
     if(mili_real<10)mili_real="00"+mili_real;
     else if(mili_real<100) mili_real="0"+mili_real;

     dateString=hour_real+""+minute_real+""+second_real+""+mili_real;
}

setInterval(checkStart,1);

function checkStart(){
    get_current();
    if(dateString==18581600){
    console.log("It's time to start");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to hit an exact time with 1 millisecond accuracy will not work. Change:

```
dateString==18581600
```

to:

```
dateString >= 18581600
```

Also, running setInterval with a 1 millisecond delay is not supported. 4ms is the minimum, but it can be longer.

When in doubt, consult the [MDN reference for setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Delay_restrictions):

> [T]he browser will automatically enforce a 4 ms minimum value for the interval.
>
> Browsers may enforce even more stringent minimum values for the interval under some circumstances, although these should not be common. Note also that the actual amount of time that elapses between calls to the callback may be longer than the given delay;